Converting a saved model to tflite and connecting it to flutter Application
I am new to Flutter development and have been using Teachable Machine to create my models and connect them to my Flutter app using the flutter_tflite: ^1.0.1 dependency. When I export a model from Teachable Machine, I receive a .tflite file and a label.txt file. The conversion model is in floating-point format.
Now, I have created my own model in Jupyter Notebook. How can I achieve the same—converting my model to a .tflite file and obtaining a label.txt file where the conversion model is in floating-point format?
I've tried converting the model to TensorFlow Lite using this code, but I'm getting a .tflite model without the labels.txt file. Additionally, I'm not sure if the conversion model is in floating-point format.using this code
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.lite as tflite
import os
Path to the directory containing the saved model
saved_model_dir = "C:\Users\PC\Desktop\models\2"
try:
# Load the model
converter = tflite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
print("Model loaded successfully.")
# Convert the model to TensorFlow Lite format
tflite_model = converter.convert()
print("Model converted successfully.")

# Specify the output directory and file name
output_dir = "C:\\Users\\PC\\Desktop\\models\\converted"
os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, "converted_model.tflite")

# Save the converted model to a file
with open(output_file, "wb") as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
print(f"Model saved successfully as {output_file}.")

except Exception as e:
print(f"An error occurred: {e}")

label.txt is a normal text file that contains the labels. You can write your own labels in the same order that you used to train the model.
You can use Netron to view your model input and outputs.

The issue is that when I run the model on the app with an image, it only shows the last label in the labels.txt file with a confidence of 99%, regardless of the image. Even if I change the images, the last label in the labels.txt file is always shown.

Most probably it is a problem with incorrect input normalization. Your model may need a different image pixel normalization that what you are using now.
